# HTTPS address still resolving (to default site) when no longer in IIS and new certificate installed

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ssl, https, bindings

I have been banging my head with this and I'm hoping its just something silly. We have changed domains and SSL certificates for 2 sites. I have removed the old certificate and removed the IIS bindings for https for both. However if you type either of the addresses in with https it is now defaulting to displaying the default site with the new certificate?

I cant find anything on Google which sort of explains a solution for this, i've had issues where a domain can point to an old certificate before. But the new sites are working fine on the new certificate and domains. But for some reason these domains are still loading when I don't want them to anymore. The binding has been removed and the certificate it was assigned to has been removed. So where is it still loading from and looking at the new certificate?

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

**Additional info added to explain the situation:**

as an example. I had 2 sites with a wildcard certificate:

http and https name.testaddress.co.uk

The http automatically redirecting you to https. Then another site under

http and https name2.testaddress.co.uk

The certificate for these domains expired and coincidentally we needed to change the domain address branding. So a new wildcard certificate was installed and new domains registered.

http and https name.newtestaddress.co.uk

and

http and https name2.newtestaddress.co.uk

These are doing as the should be and the same auto flipping to https. For some reason though even with the old certificate removed and the https records of the old addresses from IIS the original domains (https:// name.testaddress.co.uk and https://name2.testaddress.co.uk) will resolve to the default site which in this case is the new https:// name.newtestaddress.co.uk.

Thanks

PS: Sorry for the way ive had to add the domains but I don't have enough rep points.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Each site has its own IP address in the ssl binding correct?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Its Windows server 2008 and using host headers with a wildcard certificate.

Comment: More information is needed.  Can you provide a detailed example of what you're experiencing.  Replace any sensitive information with sample names if needed.  There just isn't enough to go on here.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my original post with some more information. Thanks.